# Write a new line on a txt file with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I Want to create txt file with PHP, that can save the data after input on Form.

So far I have been trying this Script

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST[S1]))
{
   $name = $_POST[name];
   $email = $_POST[email];

   $fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "w") or exit("Unable to open file!");
   $savestring = $name . "," . $email . "\n";

   fwrite($fp, $savestring);

   fclose($fp);
   echo "<h1>You data has been saved in a text file!</h1>";

?>
<form name="web_form" id="web_form" method="post" action="coba.php">
        Enter name: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        Enter email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        <input type="submit" name="S1" id="s1″ value="Submit" />
</form>
```

It Work fine and can write to file after Input Form, but if I do the second input, the txt file change to the last input.

How can I do when the second input, the last input write a new line on txt file?

May be the explanation is unclear this the example

```
    ===============================
    First Input:
    Result Txt File:

    Adam, Adam@email.com
    ===============================
    Second Input:
    Result Txt File:

    Adam, Adam@email.com
    Eve, Eve@gmail.com
    ===============================
```

Anyone can help me to Fix it?
Im very Appreciated your answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open the file in *append* mode:

```
$fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "a") or exit("Unable to open file!");
```

Or use `file_put_contents` with the `FILE_APPEND` flag:

```
file_put_contents("formdata.txt", $name . "," . $email . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

---

**Note:**

If you're running this under a Windows environment, you will need to use `\r\n`.

I.e.:

```
file_put_contents("formdata.txt", $name . "," . $email . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

The `\n` alone is sufficient under a UNIX/Linux platform but not for Windows.

You can also use the cross-platform [`PHP_EOL` pre-defined constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

```
file_put_contents("formdata.txt", $name . "," . $email . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Only change the Mode. Thanks A lot